# Polygons on Mouseover event only Activate on Borders

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api

I have a map with several polygons that have a mouseover and click event.  The mouseover event causes the polygon to change color, and the click event brings up a custom info window.  Most of the 200 or so Polygons work, but there is a handful (about ten), that only do the mouseover or click along the borders of the polygon.

Here is the link to the map. The polygons that don't work are shown.  There is one in the middle as an example of a working polygon.

http://www.houstonportmap.com/directory.php

There are also some polylines on the map, but I've checked and the polygons appear to be correct.

Comment: Have you checked to see if there's something wrong with the geometry of those broken polygons? It could be that the geometry is defined as a polyline, or the start and end points of the polygon don't match and the polygon isn't properly closed.

Comment: That's probably it, we just have to recreate the polygons.

Answer (score 1):

Polygons that behave like lines usually means the polygon isn't closed properly (first coordinate does not equal the last coordinate) or it's define as a line in the source data. Polygons defined as lines will produce rings or perimeters instead of an area.